# Using class without definition class variable

Tags: c++, oop

I'd like to do something like:

```
class StrToHex {
public:
    ??? StrToHex(std::string a) {
        return class_method1(a) + class_method2(a);
    }
private:
    std::string method1(std::string a);
    std::string method2(std::string a);
}
int main() {
    std::string var = StrToHex("FF1042");
}
```

I know that I may use StrToHex::MyFunc() or create class object, but is there any way to do without it?

Comment: Is a static function what you want?

Comment: Does it have to be a class? Looks like all you need is a function here.

Comment: C++ does not work this way. A constructor constructs. It does not return anything. You could have the constructor do whatever needs to do, and have `operator std::string` turn it into something usable. See your C++ textbook for more information about operator overloading for classes.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, I need call function, that call other, but other function must be private

Comment: You can hide the other functions in a namespace then.

Comment: Just make the other function static. It won't be visible outside of the file it is defined in.

Comment: It mean that I should call it ClassName::Function(string), I think that I can use only ClassName(string)

Comment: Create `operator std::string()` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ a constructor cannot return a value. So you cannot specify a return type for a constructor. But there are other alternative ways to achieve the same. I have used a std::string cast operator here.

```
class StrToHex {
public:
StrToHex(std::string a) {
    _data = method1(a) + method2(a);
};

operator std::string()
{
    return _data;
};
private:
std::string method1(std::string a)
{
    return std::string("Hi " + a);
};

std::string method2(std::string a)
{
    return std::string(" again " + a);
};

std::string _data;
};

int main() {
std::string var = StrToHex("FF1042");
std::cout << var;
}
```

I hope it helps!.